# Cell PickerTextField is not tappable

Tags: swiftui, uiscrollview, picker

I am trying to show a scrollview in which every cell has 3 picker text field.
However, only the last cell has a working picker text field that is tappable.

When I check BasketListCell preview it is just like I wanted. All the pickers are working well with placeholders. But in scrollview it does not.

I have 3 different listData in BasketList but ShoppingCartView repeats the first one 3 times.

so this is my cell struct Basket that has 3 Int for each picker text field.

```
struct Basket: Identifiable {
var id: Int {
    return elementID
}
var elementID: Int
var image: String
var title: String
var brand: String
var price: String
var selectionImage: String
var discountedPrice: String
var sizeSelectedIndex: Int?
var colorSelectedIndex: Int?
var itemSelectedIndex : Int?
```

}

That is my demo BasketList with 3 elements.

```
    struct BasketList {
    static let listData: [Basket] = [
            Basket(elementID: 0, image: "Tee", title: "3-Stripes Shirt", brand: "Adidas Original", price: "$79.40", selectionImage: "checkmark", discountedPrice: "$48.99", sizeSelectedIndex: 0, colorSelectedIndex: 0, itemSelectedIndex: 0),
            Basket(elementID: 0, image: "Blouse", title: "Tuxedo Blouse", brand: "Lost Ink", price: "$50.00", selectionImage: "checkmark", discountedPrice: "$34.90", sizeSelectedIndex: 0, colorSelectedIndex: 0, itemSelectedIndex: 0),
            Basket(elementID: 0, image: "Tee", title: "Linear Near Tee", brand: "Converse", price: "$28.50", selectionImage: "checkmark", discountedPrice: "$19.99", sizeSelectedIndex: 0, colorSelectedIndex: 0, itemSelectedIndex: 0)
        ]
}
```

That is my BasketCell

```
struct BasketListCell: View {
@State var isSelected: Bool = false
@State private var itemSelectedIndex : Int?
@State private var sizeSelectedIndex : Int?
@State private var colorSelectedIndex: Int?
var colors = ["Black", "Green", "Red", "Blue"]
var sizes = ["XS", "S", "M", "L", "XL", "XXL"]
var items = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
var item: Basket
var body: some View {
HStack(spacing: 20) {
            ZStack {
                PickerTextField(data: sizes, placeHolder: "Size", lastSelectedIndex: self.$sizeSelectedIndex)
                    .overlay(
                        Image(systemName: "chevron.down")
                    )
            }
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / (375/100), height: 44, alignment: .center)
            
            ZStack{
                PickerTextField(data: colors, placeHolder: "Color", lastSelectedIndex: self.$colorSelectedIndex)
                    .overlay(
                        Image(systemName: "chevron.down")
                    )
                
            }
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / (375/100), height: 44, alignment: .center)
            
            ZStack {
                PickerTextField(data: items, placeHolder: "Item", lastSelectedIndex: self.$itemSelectedIndex)
                    .overlay(
                        Image(systemName: "chevron.down")
                    )
            }
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / (375/100), height: 44, alignment: .center)
        }
       }
```

and finally, this is my ShoppingCartView

```
struct ShoppingCartView: View {
@State var selectedProduct = Basket(elementID: 0, image: "", title: "", brand: "", price: "", selectionImage: "", discountedPrice: "", sizeSelectedIndex: 0, colorSelectedIndex: 0, itemSelectedIndex: 0)
@State var shown: Bool = false
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color(.white)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        VStack {
            NavigationView {
                ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                    VStack(spacing: 20) {
                        ForEach(BasketList.listData) { item in
                            BasketListCell(item: item)
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    self.shown = true
                                    self.selectedProduct = item
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

You can understand clearly my problem if you check those images better.

This is BasketListCell preview

[image]

That is my ShoppingCartView

[image]

Comment: Your elementID is not a unique identifier for Basket objects.

Comment: I want to give you points. Can you send it as an answer. That solved my problem Tushar. I can not believe I missed it.

Comment: Sure let me post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`elementID` attribute of your  Model class `Basket` needs to be unique. You currently have 3 `Basket` objects all with duplicate `identifier`, causing swiftUI to read first object every time. Changing it to some unique values should fix the problem.

**Current-:**

```
struct BasketList {
    static let listData: [Basket] = [
            Basket(elementID: 0, image: "Tee", title: "3-Stripes Shirt", brand: "Adidas Original", price: "$79.40", selectionImage: "checkmark", discountedPrice: "$48.99", sizeSelectedIndex: 0, colorSelectedIndex: 0, itemSelectedIndex: 0),
            Basket(elementID: 0, image: "Blouse", title: "Tuxedo Blouse", brand: "Lost Ink", price: "$50.00", selectionImage: "checkmark", discountedPrice: "$34.90", sizeSelectedIndex: 0, colorSelectedIndex: 0, itemSelectedIndex: 0),
            Basket(elementID: 0, image: "Tee", title: "Linear Near Tee", brand: "Converse", price: "$28.50", selectionImage: "checkmark", discountedPrice: "$19.99", sizeSelectedIndex: 0, colorSelectedIndex: 0, itemSelectedIndex: 0)
        ]
}
```

**Fix-:**

```
struct BasketList {
    static let listData: [Basket] = [
            Basket(elementID: 1, image: "Tee", title: "3-Stripes Shirt", brand: "Adidas Original", price: "$79.40", selectionImage: "checkmark", discountedPrice: "$48.99", sizeSelectedIndex: 0, colorSelectedIndex: 0, itemSelectedIndex: 0),
            Basket(elementID: 2, image: "Blouse", title: "Tuxedo Blouse", brand: "Lost Ink", price: "$50.00", selectionImage: "checkmark", discountedPrice: "$34.90", sizeSelectedIndex: 0, colorSelectedIndex: 0, itemSelectedIndex: 0),
            Basket(elementID: 3, image: "Tee", title: "Linear Near Tee", brand: "Converse", price: "$28.50", selectionImage: "checkmark", discountedPrice: "$19.99", sizeSelectedIndex: 0, colorSelectedIndex: 0, itemSelectedIndex: 0)
        ]
}
```